# Select data by month

Tags: sql

I Need help to select a number of data per month, there are 4 retailers and I need to select a  total of transactions per month and the total amount for that month showing each month separately in sql.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the month from the date and group by it. Then you can use aggregate functions to sum and count

```
select month(date_column), 
       sum(amount) as total_amount, 
       count(*) as transaction_count
from your_table
group by month(date_column)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help, but the count and sum does not work when I use the month, any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I made a error in the script, it works now